# Using mongoclient I am unable to add a key of type BinData in mongo collection from python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When I run this query in console it works fine:

```
db.testColl.updateMany({},{ "$set": {"__class" : BinData(128, "QXRzXFF1b3RlXE1vZGVsXFF1b3Rl")} })
```

But when I try to do the same from a python program it says 'BinData is not defined'

### python code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["test"]
mycol = mydb["testColl"]

mycol.update_many({},{ "$set": {"__bclass" : BinData(128, "QXRzXFF1b3RlXE1vZGVsXFF1b3Rl")} })
```

Error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'BinData' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

> python program it says 'BinData is not defined'

You're seeing this error message because `BinData` is a [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) shell utility to represent [BSON Type Binary Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types).

In Python this is represented differently using [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/). If you're using **Python3** then you can just use the Python bytes type. For example:

```
data = b"Ats\\Quote\\Model\\Quote"
collection.update_many({}, {"$set":{"__class": data }})
```

This will result in value `BinData(0, "QXRzXFF1b3RlXE1vZGVsXFF1b3Rl")` in the MongoDB collection.

If you're using **Python2**, the data must be wrapped as an instance of `bson.binary.Binary` from the [bson module](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html#module-bson).

> BinData(128, "QXRzXFF1b3RlXE1vZGVsXFF1b3Rl")

Also, worth mentioning that the way you construct `BinData` is not common BSON (although you may have a special reason).

`BinData` takes parameters in the form of `BinData(subtype, base64str)`. The subtype is utilised to indicate what kind of data is in the byte array. According to the [BSON specifications](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) generic binary subtype is `0`. This is the most commonly used binary subtype and should be the 'default' for MongoDB drivers (i.e. PyMongo) and tools.

While subtypes from zero to 127 are predefined or reserved, subtypes from 128-255 are user-defined. Unless you're purposely specifying 128 to define your own type, I would suggest to use `0`.